# Не видит txt файл после сборки

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

Добрый день.

После сборки проекта программа не находит текстовый файл, который находится внутри jar-ника.

Вот код:

```
BufferedReader in=null;
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("info/help_EN.txt"));
```

Есть проект Just pic, в нем package JustPicProgram, в нем папка info, а в ней уже сам файл. До сборки, в IDEA, все было нормально, теперь ничего не видит.

Answer (score 1):

В папке info размести класс `MyBeautifulClass`, и потом пиши так

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(MyBeautifulClass.class.getResourse("help_EN.txt")));
```